# How to fix " Failed to instantiate 'className' using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments" in immutable class

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I use MongoDBRepository in spring boot, and when I save some object in database everything is ok. but when I find object by id spring does not allow do that.

I try to change VehicleRoutingProblemSolution type to Object type, but  VehicleRoutingProblemSolution have other object field PickupService and it without default constructor to. And yes, this class has immutable... I can't create default constructors, what can I do?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.graphhopper.jsprit.core.problem.solution.VehicleRoutingProblemSolution;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "vrp_solutions")
public class VrpSolutionHolder {
    // Specifies the solution id
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    // Specifies the solution id
    @JsonProperty("solution")
    private VehicleRoutingProblemSolution vehicleRoutingProblemSolution;

    // Created at timestamp in millis
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private Long created_at = System.currentTimeMillis();


    public VrpSolutionHolder(String id, VehicleRoutingProblemSolution vehicleRoutingProblemSolution) {
        this.id = id;
        this.vehicleRoutingProblemSolution = vehicleRoutingProblemSolution;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public VehicleRoutingProblemSolution getVehicleRoutingProblemSolution() {
        return vehicleRoutingProblemSolution;
    }

    public void setVehicleRoutingProblemSolution(VehicleRoutingProblemSolution vehicleRoutingProblemSolution) {
        this.vehicleRoutingProblemSolution = vehicleRoutingProblemSolution;
    }

    public Long getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(Long created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
}
```

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   com.graphhopper.jsprit.core.problem.solution.VehicleRoutingProblemSolution
>   using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem. A persistent immutable class containing other class instances, throwing that aforementioned exception when retrieved by this repository method:

```
public interface ProjectCodeCacheRepository extends MongoRepository<CachedCode, String> {
    public CachedCode findByCode(String code);  
    public List<CachedCode> findByClientId(UUID clientId);
}
...
List<CachedCode> cachedForClient = this.codeCacheRepo.`**findByClientId**`(clientId);
...
```

Following Erwin Smouts hints, this is nicely fixed by giving it a special constructor.

Prior to spring boot 3.0 the annotation used was:  `org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor`

After this version, the annotation was deprecated in favor of: `org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceCreator`

Like so:

```
@Document(collection="cachedcodes")
public class CachedCode {
    
    @PersistenceCreator
    public CachedCode(String code, UUID clientId, LocalDateTime expiration) {
        this.code = code;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.expiration = expiration;
    }
    
    public CachedCode(String code, UUID clientId, long secondsExpiring) {
        this.code = code;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.expiration = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(secondsExpiring);
    }
    
    
    public UUID getClientId( ) {
        return this.clientId;
    }
            
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }
        
    public boolean hasExpired(LocalDateTime now) {
        return (expiration.isBefore(now));
    }
    
    ...
    @Id
    private final String code;
    private final UUID clientId;
    private final LocalDateTime expiration;
}
```

So, you should check if your VehicleRoutingProblemSolution has a) a constructor that matches the database fields (check in mongo client) and b) is annotated to be the one used by the driver (or whichever piece of Spring magic under the hood).

Comment: Brilliant, I knew a constructor annotation existed but just did not know it, you are a life saver.

Comment: The PersistentConstructor doesn't have to be 'public', I prefer letting it as 'protected' to indicate it is not meant to be used by other client classes. It can even be 'private', it works.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using lombok, you need to remove the `@Builder` annotation on your class and use `@Data` instead, or follow the above solution to provide a specialized constructor

Answer (score 1):

If your framework tool ***requires*** (visible) no-arg constructors (plus accompanying setters), and the class you have is ***required*** to stay as is, then you could roll your own, say, MutableVehicleRoutingProblemSolution where in the setters you could have :

```
this.vehicleRoutingProblemSolution = new VehicleRoutingProblemSolution(vehicleRoutingProblemSolution.getId(), newSolution);
```

Thus your MutableVehicleRoutingProblemSolution wraps around the existing VehicleRoutingProblemSolution.

Hacky smell to it, but it fits the requirements.

(Or you could try to find a tool that is able to use, not annotations on the contained fields, but annotations on constructor arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem where the corresponding class does not have a no-arg constructor like - I was facing an issue with java.io.File.

Solution:
In general - change the declaration to Object class and convert where we are using the class.

**from**

```
class MyClass{

    File myfile;

}
```

**to**

```
class MyClass{

    Object myFile;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, I received this when I attempted to decorate a custom interface with ...

```
@Document(collection = "Person")
```

Example:

```
package test.barry.interfaces;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.UpdateDefinition;


@Document(collection = "Person")
public interface CustomRepository
{
    void updatex(Query filterPredicate, UpdateDefinition updatePredicate);
}
```